# Slang names for souteneur

Tags: single-word-requests, slang, offensive-language

What are some common slang names for the souteneur - the illicit "manager" for prostitutes?

I'm fairly sure there are a few, but I can't find any in the common online resources and I need it for a fiction story - souteneur sounds way too 'official'.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Perhaps there's a subtlety here I missed, but "pimp" is a common word (too common perhaps to be slang?).

Similarly "panderer" or "procurer", though "pimp" is more easily understood as claiming exclusive marketing rights.

Comment: "Pimp" is what I'd go for. Or for a female manager, "[madam](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/madam#Noun)".

Comment: In fact, Merriam Webster gives "pimp" as the *definition* of "souteneur" (which is actually marked as "misspelled" by the Chrome spellchecker).

Answer (score 8):

*Souteneur* is French. Its first meaning in French is supporter or backer. Its second meaning is the one you allude to. The more common name for this in French is *maquereau*, or just *mack* viz. Mack the Knife. (*Maquerelle* if it's a woman) and the legal word is *proxénète*. With just Google translate you should find the word you want.

Comment: Oh wow, so that’s where *mack daddy* comes from?

Comment: Mack the Knife was not a pimp. His name was MacHeath. This is the origin of *mack daddy* though.

Answer (score 6):

**Ponce** is another definition  for someone in the business of prostitution.

Ponce: 
1. a person, esp. a man, who solicits customers for a prostitute or a brothel, usu. in return for a share of the earnings; procurer.

Source: Collins Dictionary

Comment: That's a good answer and could only be improved by adding a link for the word.

Comment: Beware: in some dialects, "ponce" is also a derogatory term for an effete man or a gay man.

Answer (score 4):

[Cadet](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/cadet): [*slang*] a procurer.

[mack daddy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mack+daddy): [*slang*] a conspicuously successful pimp.

[fancy man](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fancy+man): [*slang*] someone who procures customers for whores (In England they call a pimp a ponce).

Comment: I don't think that definition of "ponce" is in common use in the UK any more -- at least, I'd neve heard it before. As far as I can tell, we mostly call pimps pimps.

Answer (score 0):

In colonial Australia it was a "bludger"; nowadays a "pimp".